# How to Showcase Your Work As A Beginner

Tags: writing

I'm primarily a freelance writer and I've just got into amateur photography.

In both fields my interests are extremely broad, so I'd like to jump into all areas and see where it takes me.

With writing, I plan on writing regular articles on a new set of micro blogs that I have developped, and with photography, I plan on creating a few "photo of the day" / "365 Day" Projects that will allow me to get out there for a bit of experience.

In both cases, my portfolio is likely to be extremely varied, ranging from Nature & Local Events to Music & Alternative to Horror & Macabre to more NSFW based content.

As someone who is not big on social media I'm wondering what the best way to publicise the content that I create would be. I don't want to own 101 twitter accounts to cover different aspects of my work, yet at the same time, I understand that my work will appeal to a number of different audiences, some of whom may be offended by certain aspects of my work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

First off, the hardest part of starting out is starting out. Get taking your pictures, and write sample content that you have the ability to post.

Build up a portfolio of all your best works, and build a website out of it. The website will act as your resume. Make the URL short and sweet, but still professional. If it's too long, only die-hard users will bother remembering it.

Use a CMS program, unless you are an HTML and CSS wizard, and build a website that looks good, and does not cost very much to maintain. You are looking to just get your content out there, then you can focus on advertising it.

Once it's up and running, as a friend or family member to critique it for you. Are there spelling or grammatical errors? Are the pictures blurry or clear? What is their initial impression?

Once you have this done, you can start advertising the website, and your Freelancing company, and start looking for customers.

Comment: Thanks Luke, but maybe there's a slight missunderstanding here. This is more about how to reach a targeted audience with the use of only one website. I have a site that I can use as a portfolio for written mork, photography, music, art, etc, but my problem is that all niches will be shown in the same place, where local events / people photography/articles will be mixed in with more NSFW content such as horror & fetish. Without owning multiple social accounts, how can you freely communicate with a wide audience who will no doubt like some areas of your work, but possibly be offended by others?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that having a wide range of proposed areas is not a problem, but an advantage.
As a rule, if a person turns to the photographer, it means that he can't take professional-grade photos on his own, and it means that the photographer may be needed for him more than once and for more than one genre (now or in the future). If you declare only one direction of your activity, there is a probability that for performing some multicomponent task he will address not only to you, but also to other photographer(s), without knowing that you can do all parts of this task yourself!
The same goes for writing.
Do not be afraid to seem versatile developed specialist. I repeat: this is your advantage!

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I do see my range of interests as an advantage, and the website/portfolio that I have built will effectively allow me to showcase exactly what I can do in all areas. So the main problem I have isn't so much the wesbite, but how to run a single social media presence, which can be seen by potentially every single person who follows me. On the one hand, people interested in my nature photos may have an interest in my fetish work, but on the other hand, followers who I work with at local events may change their oppinion of me for doing adult themed work.

Comment: In this case, it makes sense to divide your portfolio and your social contacts into two groups: "nude/erotic/fetish/bdsm" and "everything else". It seems to me that everything outside the first group will be compatible with each other.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. It seems like that will be the way to go, but I was hoping to reduce my number of hours switching between accounts and personalities so I can focus more on actually producing quality work and content. - I've asked a similar question at https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/social-networking-as-a-multi-niche-freelancer which explains things better

Comment: @WayneFA, good luck with that!