# Social Networking As A Multi-Niche Freelancer

Tags: communication

As an individual, as I'm sure most of us are, I have an extremely broad range of interests. Anything from Nature and wildlife, to rock and heavy metal lifestyle interests ( bands, tattoos, beer, alternative models, etc ), to horror ( from mainstream to the macabre ), to various forms of NSFW ( erotic art, fetish, BDSM ).

So as a blogger and amateur photographer who wants to take it more seriously into the new year, I devised a website which will allow me to showcase my written articles, photography, artwork, music, etc, etc, in any number of fields of interest.

So the website/portfolio side of things isn't an issue based on the way I've built it. What is an issue is actually connecting with people who I'm going to write about, photograph, or become involved with on an ongoing professional basis.

I'm not big on social networks, but in the past I've split myself into so many different personalities to account for my range of interests that I'm past wanting to do that again. It's time consuming, tiring and makes you question just who you're actually trying to target.

So for me, a single use Twitter account, Pinterest account, DeviatArt account seems like the way to go. However, is it right to showcase/talk about all of your interests in one place, considering your followers will range from local mothers and event organisers to fetish models and film producers.

**For Clarification:** This is less about the actual content that you publish on social media, but the ability for ALL followers to gain an insight into ALL of your interests and activities, whether considered to be normal/everyday or kinky/NSFW.

Do any of you have this issue and how do you run your social media effectively?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the right division: Twitter / Facebook with a real name for local mothers and DeviantArt with an artistic pseudonym for fetish models.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. In theory this works well, but twitter and facebook are the two major players in social networking, and the places you're most likely to pick up local clients. DA is a great place to showcase your own and comment on others work, but it's just not that effective on a local scale. Plus, it's become a joke over the past year or so, with selfies and photomanipulations galore, and art that looks great if done by a 3 year old. Unfortunately.